# Code completion for Eclipse with PCL on ROS electric

Tags: pcl, eclipse, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to use PCL with ROS, but it seems that my eclipse is not automatically configured for PCL-related services to use code completion. The general ROS code has no problem at all. I am using ROS electric anyway. Hopefully any eclipse user/developer can guide me on this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11610/code-completion-for-eclipse-with-pcl-on-ros-electric/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem, using electric, and I finally solved it, I can't tell exactly how, but I'll tell you the steps I followed

1- Remove everything in folder CMakeList and file CMakeCache.txt
2- If you called on the that package "make eclipse-project", then remove .cprojet and .project files
3- My dependancy in manifest.xml is as follows:








and yes I know there are some redundancies, but maybe this is what helped in my case

4- After that call the following inside your package:
rosmake --pre-clean --rosdep-install

5- Finally call:  cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"
6- Then import the project into eclipse. In my case it worked

Good luck

---

Originally posted by [Moataz Elmasry](https://answers.ros.org/users/116/moataz-elmasry/) with karma: 126 on 2011-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moataz Elmasry](https://answers.ros.org/users/116/moataz-elmasry/) on 2011-12-01**:
if you already have imported  the project under eclipse, then please remove it before applying these steps